# Restrict access to record types based on lightning app

Tags: lightning, sharing

In an org I have 2 lightning app (app 1 and app2), all my users nedd access to both apps , the aim is that when I am in the app1 I can create  only account with record type RT1 and when I'm in the app 2 I can create only account with record type RT2. I Have 2 lightning record page (RP1 assigned to RT 1 and app1) an another record page (RP2 assigned to RT2 and app2), my problem that in the app1 i can see all account (RT1 and RT2) and in the app2 I can see all account too. How could i do so in the app1 I can see only account RT1 and in the app2 I can see  only account with RT2

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same question and found that another user asked a similar question. Please follow the below link

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DNXcAAO&_ga=2.25425915.779987550.1662432274-338901508.1652425432

I have not implemented the suggested solution but would love to know if it solves the problem for you.